# Resolve promise using Node/Express before registering middleware and exposing routes

Tags: node.js, express, aws-lambda, passport.js

I'm using serverless-express to deploy my application to AWS lambda and am having trouble dealing with asynchronous code.

I need to fetch a secret from a secrets manager using an async request to use for my middleware, but I find that I get no response or a timed out one when I try and wrap my middleware and routes in a promise chain.

`handler.js` imports `app.js`, which is used as an argument `serverlessExpress` below

handler.js

```
module.exports.handler = serverlessExpress({app}).handler
```

app.js

```
getSecret().then(secret => {
  const strategy = new OAuth2Strategy({
    secret: secret
  }, function (accessToken, refreshToken, params, profile, done) {
    done(null,{data: 'some user data'});
  })


  passport.use('oauth2', strategy);
  refresh.use('oauth2', strategy);

  app.get('/my_route', async function (req, res) {
    ...
  })
})
```

What is the best way to deal with async code that needs to be resolved before I expose my routes?

Comment: Provide exactly `serverless-express` npm link.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted it is not enough to understand the context. I am assuming that the handler script is imported by app script and at this time app object is not defined yet so you passed in the serverlessExpress an undefined variable.
During the bootstrap phase, I suggest the following flow:

1. define an async function which helps in awaiting other infrastructure configs/data
2. load all necessary configs
3. create express app
4. attach middleware and routes to app
5. create serverless express

A code snippet:

```
async function boot() {
    //load all configurations
    const secrets = await getSecret();

    //after everything is ready create app
    let app = express();

    //load all routes etc
}
```

Using async/await result in a more cleaner code than using promises. The nesting decreases readiness.